# Can Travis-ci be used without Github

Tags: git, travis-ci

For example :

- Can I setup Travis-ci for a private gitlab server repository ?
- Can I host travis at my company and use it internally, or do I need to open my git server port to the exterior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis CI at travis-ci.com requires Github. See [Prerequisites](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/#prerequisites): A GitHub account is a must.

Your company can buy an [enterprise version](https://enterprise.travis-ci.com/) to run Travis CI on premise.

Or you can install any [free ci/cd](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=free+ci%2Fcd).

Comment: Does it mean that I can host Travic CI Enterprise version in my company ?
Does it mean I can provide it with a custom git repository not hosted at GitHub ?

Comment: I believe it's "yes" for both questions.